# How to exclude a date from a condition with count?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am writing a query to count a variable where the date is between `201801` and `201812`  and I want to exclude the variable whose date is `201806`. How can I achieve it?

This is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT COUNT (Var1) as 'varCount' 
from Vartable 
inner join UserTable on usr_id 
where usr_login = 'bella' 
  and Var_Date between 201801 and 201812
```

Comment: What type of column is `Var_Date`? Doesn't appear to be of any date-type?

Comment: In the system it s an int that's why it's in this format

Comment: Why not use an actual date type? That way you can actually use the date-related functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Var_Date not in (201806)` with your where condition

```sql
SELECT COUNT (Var1) as 'varCount' 
from Vartable inner join UserTable on usr_id 
where usr_login = 'bella' 
  and Var_Date between 201801 and 201812 
  and Var_Date not in (201806)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your date is stored as a date, then the comparisons should be dates as well.  I would suggest:

```
select count(Var1) as varCount 
from Vartable inner join
     UserTable
     on usr_id 
where usr_login = 'bella' and
      (var_date >= '20180101' and var_date < '20180601' or
       var_date >= '20180701' and var_date < '20190101'
      )
```

If the column you are calling `var_date` is really an integer that represents a month, then I would recommend renaming it.  And then you can simply do:

```
where usr_login = 'bella' and
      yyyymm >= 201801 and
      yyyymm <= 201812 and
      yyyymm <> 201806
```

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude the `201806` in the `WHERE` clause as

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 201801 Var_Date 
  UNION
  SELECT 201802
  UNION
  SELECT 201803
  UNION
  SELECT 201804
  UNION
  SELECT 201805
  UNION
  SELECT 201806
  UNION
  SELECT 201807
  UNION
  SELECT 201808
  UNION
  SELECT 201809
  UNION
  SELECT 201810
  UNION
  SELECT 201811
  UNION
  SELECT 201812
  UNION
  SELECT 201901
  UNION
  SELECT 201902
)

SELECT COUNT(1) Cnt
FROM CTE
WHERE Var_Date BETWEEN 201801 AND 201812
      AND Var_Date != 201806;
```

If the column is `DATE`, then you can do as

```
SELECT COUNT(Var1) VarCount
FROM VarTable V INNER JOIN UserTable U
ON V.UserId = U.UserId --Don't forget the JOIN conditions
WHERE U.Usr_Login = 'bella'
      AND
      Var_Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
      AND
      Var_Date NOT BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-06-30'
```

You can also use `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` as

```
SELECT COUNT(Var1) VarCount
FROM VarTable V INNER JOIN UserTable U
ON V.UserId = U.UserId --Don't forget the JOIN conditions
WHERE U.Usr_Login = 'bella'
      AND
      MONTH(Var_Date) <> 6
      AND
      YEAR(Var_Date) = 2018;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(Var1) as 'varCount' 
from Vartable 
inner join UserTable on usr_id 
where usr_login = 'bella' 
  and Var_Date between '201801' and '201812'
  and Var_Date <> '201806'
```

Comment: **1.** OP wrote that Var_Date is int **2.** `not <>` is incorrect

Comment: Hey there. Consider also writing a few words on how you came up to this solution.